# How to typecast double to DWORDLONG or DWORD to DWORDLONG or DWORD_PTR to DWORDLONG

Tags: c++, visual-c++, casting, mfc

I have 
m_listControl.SetItemData(iIndex, (DWORD)GetId(i));

GetId returns double value, if the returned value is crossed the range (DWORD range 0 - 4,294,967,295)

m_listControl.GetItemData(Item); is returning the garbage value.

Here i am converting returned double value to DWORD.

Please suggest how to handle the value.

Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://$SITEURL$/help/mcve) that demonstrates 
your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: You need a much bigger hammer, double the size of the one you have available..  Or a pointy one.  Separate the data from the view to get ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Your `double` is 64 bits, and you plan to store it in a DWORD` which is 32 bits. A typecast isn't going to change that reality - you don't have enough bits.

Create a `std::map<DWORD, double>` or other lookup structure.

Comment: Thank you. Your input helped me to solve this issue.